# How to make UI specific to players?

Tags: multiplayer, gui, godot

How can I implement a system in my application's user interface (UI) where certain UI elements are selectively visible to specific players, ensuring that each player, such as Player A, can exclusively view and interact with their own inventory, while preventing other players, like Player B, from accessing or seeing Player A's inventory?

Comment: Just to confirm: these players are playing concurrently over a network, each with their own separate device/display?

Comment: @DMGregory yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the entity has authority before activating the UI :)

```
if is_multiplayer_authority()
```